# CSS media queries don't working

Tags: css, media-queries

Hello I've created a website, 3 weeks ago the media queries and everything worked and I take a  break. Now that I'm testing again the site the media queries don't work (yes it just freaking messed up).

Here are my media queries:

```
/* Media Queries */

@media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

    #ad-container, #ad, #adnum, #adnums, #adStxt, #footer {
        display: none;
    }

    #adtxtspecial {
    display: block;
    }

    #content {
    padding-left: 0px;
    }

    #project-logo {
    display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {

    #header {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

In the head of the document I got this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width = device-width;">
```

Please answer as soon as posible.

**EDIT: These are the original styles for the elements that I need to change.**

```
#ad-container {
  text-align: center;
}

#ad {
  width: 900px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  display: block;
}

#adnums {
   padding: 2px;
   background-color: #f7f6f5;
   cursor: pointer;
}

#adnum {
   color: #dd4814;
   font-weight: bold;
}

#adStxt {
   font-size: small;
}

#adtxtspecial {
   display: none;
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 40px;
   color: #dd4814;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-top: 100px;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell what is not working?

Comment: "don't work" is not a very specific explanation.

Comment: @yotam-omer Well more specifically when I resize the window some objects should dissappear (display: none) and other objects should appear (display: block). But is not happening.

Comment: It should work. What is the default CSS you use?

Comment: @itaygal What you mean with that?

Comment: When the screen is wider than 980px, what css properties are you using? are you using an inline style?

Comment: @itaygal Is a bit long so I'm going to edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I can think about is that you are using an inline style. the inline style overrides the style properties from the CSS section/file.

[here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ayFgr/1/)

I added this CSS:

```
#content{
    padding-left:50px;
}
```

Note that you should not use 2 different element's with the same ID but for that example it works and it demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Actually I'm not using inline styles

Comment: OK, but I still don't see any problem. The elements disappear when I resize the window and I'm using your code.

Answer (score 0):

Better practice is to use classes for this kind of thing. See if changing them into classes rectifies the issues.

Comment: OK I just found out that it doesn't work locally, but when I opened it in localhost it works! I still don't understand why the hell it doesn't work locally but at least it works.